# 'git commit --amend' in detached HEAD state

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-commit, git-amend

I understand that the correct way of amending an old Git commit is to use `rebase --interactive`, but just to get clear on the concepts, I would like to understand what happens when I do

- `git checkout <commit>`
- change something in a file
- add the changed file to the index
- and then `git commit . --amend`

When I do this, instead of amending the commit, it branches a new commit off of the PARENT of that same commit.

Is this just Git's way of telling me that I cannot amend a commit that already has children commits?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Git, once a commit is created, it's set in stone; you cannot change it. All you can do—by amending it, cherry-picking it, etc.—is create a new commit that "resembles" it.

I understand your confusion: "amend" is a bit of a misnomer; it's somewhat misleading, as it suggests modifying something in place. In Git, *amending a commit* actually consists in creating a *brand new* commit that has the same parent(s) as the original commit.

As an example, let's assume that, after running `git checkout B`, you're in the following situation:

[image]

(Your `HEAD` is detached, but that's beside the point.) Whether or not you make and stage changes, running `git commit --amend` will put you in this situation:

[image]

Commit `D` may be very, *very* similar to `B`; in particular, it may have exactly the same patch, exactly the same commit message as `B`, etc.. However, (commit, author) timestamps will usually differ ([unless you can amend a commit under a second!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237043/what-is-the-resolution-of-gits-commit-date-or-author-date-timestamps/28238046#28238046)), which means the SHA-1 of `D` will differ from that of `B`; and if two commits don't have the same SHA, they're not the same commit.

When we say *`B` is a parent commit of `C`*, we mean *commit `C` references commit `B` by its SHA*.
However, commit `C` has no way of knowing anything about the SHA of commit `D`, because commit `D` was created *after* `C`. Therefore, `D` cannot be `C`'s parent. That's why commit `D` goes off on a tangent and doesn't have any descendants.

---

If you want to land in the following state,

[image]

where `B'` is even only slightly different from `B`, you should use `git rebase -i`, not `git commit --amend`.