# How does git commit --amend work, exactly?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-amend

I have seen *['git commit --amend' in detached HEAD state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948049/git-commit-amend-in-detached-head-state/25948372#25948372)*. The question requires the answer to be more complex than needs be.

I'd like to understand just how `git commit --amend` works in a normal HEAD situation.

Comment: Found this awesome article: https://medium.com/@igor_marques/git-basics-adding-more-changes-to-your-last-commit-1629344cb9a8

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Assume that you're in a clean working state and that your repository looks as follows:

[image]

If you then run

```
git commit --amend
```

write a commit message, save and quit your editor, the following happens:

1. Your staging area—which, if you haven't staged any new changes, will be identical to commit *f42c5*—is used to create a new commit: *31b8e*. Its parent(s) will be the same as that (those) of the commit you're amending: *f42c5*.
2. The *master* branch reference is moved to point to that new commit (*31b8e*).
3. The *HEAD* reference follows *master*.

[image]

Note that the amended commit (*f42c5*) is now unreachable from any reference in your repository (hence its "transparent" style on my graph). It still lives in your repository's object database, but it will eventually be deleted for good, when Git runs its periodic housekeeping, or if you trigger it explicitly by running `git gc` (garbage collection).

---

**Addendum** (based on [Jason Baker's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly/26050416#comment40810131_26050416)): Note that, as long as the amended commit, *f42c5*, still exists in your repository and you have a way of finding out its commit ID (for example, by fishing it out of the *master* branch's reflog), you can still check it out. Running

```
git checkout master # just to be sure that master is the current branch
git reset --hard f42c5
```

or (assuming you haven't, in the meantime, made any new commit on *master*, reset *master*, or otherwise moved the *master* branch reference)

```
git checkout master # just to be sure that master is the current branch
git reset --hard master@{1}
```

would put you in the following situation:

[image]

However, commit *31b8e* would now be unreachable.

---

Comment: Can you get back to `f42c5` by doing a `checkout`, or by going through the reflog? I admit that it would be a silly thing to do, but I'm curious if the old commit can be accessed *at all*

Comment: @JasonBaker Yes, you can always check out the amended (now unreachable) commit, as long as it has hasn't been garbage collected, and you have a way of referring to it.

Comment: Heh, now the commands are not quite right, `git reset` *always* resets the *current* branch (which means `HEAD` must not be detached, too).  Put the `checkout master` first, etc...

Comment: @torek Sh*t... I'll get it eventually... It's too late for this kind of gymnastics, in my time zone `:)`

Comment: Not if you're already on it.  It's just to make sure that we know what `reset` is re-setting.

Comment: @torek I'll add it for safety.

Comment: @jub0bs could I said that when something goes wrong with a commit (data corrruption or something) I could use the the --amend parameter to rebase from the previous pointer but including the stage? I'm not sure how normal is that but I had a few of those situations (data corruption) and I fixed them manually because those were personal projects.. [new repo :D]

Comment: I would assume a common use case for amend is that you forgot to include a change or that you included a change too many. Do you do something before the amend to set the staging status to pre-commit status or does git figure out how to combine f4 with the staging status automatically? Since you are working on top of f4 then most of the intended changes are already checked in.

Answer (score 11):

Say you just committed "B"

```
... --- A --- B
              ^
              |
            master
             HEAD
```

Amending "B" will create a parallel commit which becomes the new branch head.

```
        +---- B
        |
... --- A --- B'
              ^
              |
            master
             HEAD
```

B' is the commit resulting from a combination of the changes from B plus the changes you had staged when you issued the `git commit --amend`.

Comment: To build on this answer, B' will contain the combination of the changes from B, and any staged changes that you have sitting in your repo right now

Comment: What is meant by *"combination"*, exactly? Perhaps update the answer?

Comment: `B' is the commit resulting from a combination of the changes from B plus the changes you had staged when you issued the git commit --amend. `

is very important for me. Until now I used to use `git commit --amend` only to change commit messages. I didn't know I could use `git commit --amend` to update changes in a commit.

Comment: @bit Absolutely.  In fact, I often use `-C HEAD` (instead of `-m'...'`) to *avoid* changing the message.

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge, *amend* works thus:

For `git commit --amend` works the changes to amend must be into the *stagging area (SA)*

1. It makes `git reset -- soft` for bring back changes committed in the last commit (commit to amend) to the SA and move the index to previous commit (commit before commit to amend). Everything keep how it was before the `git commit` command were used.
2. It makes `git add` with all files to add to new commit (it will be the *amended commit*). The files to add are those were into the SA before the `git reset --soft` was landed, and after reset these files are kept in the working directory (WD), so it is necessary add them to the SA for generate the *amended commit*.
3. It makes a Git commit. It will generate a new commit and hence a new id for the *amended commit*. For this, `git commit --amend` should not be used with *pushed commits*.

If you use `--no-edit` the comment is reused in the *amended commit*, else you must introduce a new comment (because it is a new commit and every commit needs a comment).

For more information about the staging area and working directory, see *[Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html)*.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you create two files test1.txt and test2.txt then you you run

```
git add test1.txt && git commit -m “test1.txt and test2.txt “
```

later you remember you did not add test2.txt
So you want to add the missing test2.txt file and modify the previous commit
git add test2.txt

```
git commit --amend -m "test1.txt & test2.txt added"

git log [to see that the previous commit message updated and test2.txt file added]
```