# Add file deletion to last commit

Tags: git

I've just performed a commit, but now I see that an additional file, which I've just untracked via `git rm --cached myfile.txt`, should also be included in that commit. How do I do this? Do I need to reset that last commit and perform it again? Or is there a way do include this file change into the existing commit?

Answer (score 4):

`git commit --amend` is what you're looking for. Stage your changes, then do `git commit --amend` to combine them with the last commit. You shouldn't do this, though, if you've already pushed the original changes up to somewhere other developers would have them.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-commit--amend

Comment: More about `git commit --amend`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly/26050416#26050416