# Can't rename last synchronized commit

Tags: git, github

How can I rename my last commit, which I already synchronized with github?

This doesn't work:

```
git commit --amend -m "New name"
```

[image]

[image]

When the command completes displays the new name. But if I synchronize a project with github, then displayed again old wrong name.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by "doesn't work", and probably also what you mean by "rename a commit" (commits don't have anything called a "name", just author+committer+tree+parents+log message).

Comment: @torek The question is indeed very unclear; I'm guessing that, by "doesn't work", the OP means that he can't push his amended commit.

Comment: @torek I've execute command from my question and nothing happens. Name does not changed. Under the name I understand that highlighted in red in the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewording a commit message is equivalent to changing the commit itself from a branch history point of view. In both cases you are changing the hash of the commit. Since you have already pushed that branch to GitHub, your next push will fail unless you force

```
git push origin master -f
```

Your modification won't appear on the remote until you do that. You can, however, see that it's been correctly modified locally using `git log` or visually with `gitk --all`

Comment: *Rewording a commit message is equivalent to changing the commit itself.* [Not exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly/26050416#26050416).

Comment: From a branch history point of view it is -- both have the effect of changing the HASH of the commit. That's what I meant, I'll edit.

Comment: Should I first execute your command and then mine? If yes, then unfortunately it still doesn't works