# Is there a light-touch way to alter a single file that was accidentally committed?

Tags: git, git-revert, git-amend

I made a commit containing ten files recently.  One of the files shouldn't have been committed: it has my local test changes that won't work for anyone else.

I'd like to check out that file from a previous commit, then re-commit it as the original, then reapply my changes locally.

`git revert` sounds good, but it appears to be for entire commits, rather than one file in a commit.  Is there a good way to go about this while keeping the git chatter/logs to a minimum? Amend the previous commit perhaps?

None of this has been pushed yet, if that helps.

Comment: Have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 4):

> `git revert` sounds good, but it appears to be for entire commits, rather than one file in a commit.

There is no light-touch way of changing a commit. If you want to change even a tiny little thing in an existing commit, you have to create a new one (with a new SHA) that merely resembles the original one.

> Is there a good way to go about this while keeping the git chatter/logs to a minimum? (Amend the previous commit perhaps?)

If the commit in question is not the last one on the branch, `git commit --amend` won't help you much; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly/26050416#26050416) for an explanation. You can either use `git revert` or...

> None of this has been pushed yet, if that helps...

Since you haven't pushed to remote yet (yes, it does help), you can always do an [interactive rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) to rewrite the history of your branch from the point where the offending file was first introduced onwards.

Answer (score 3):

If it hasn't been pushed - you're golden, you can rewrite history as you please.

Amending the commit is a great idea, if your commit is the last one on the branch (if not - don't worry, as it isn't pushed you can rewrite history fairly simply anyway). To get the "old" version of the file you can just check it out from the previous commit with command `git checkout COMMIT-HASH-ID path_to_file`.

So, if your `git log --oneline` looks output looks like this -

```
 $ git log --oneline
9ab100f Your awesome 10-file commit message
e62c6d5 Merge pull request #607 from origin/someone-elses-feature
cfdf47a someone elses commit message
```

Just do

```
git checkout e62c6d5 path/to/your_file_name.js
```

Then add it to stage

```
git add .
```

then amend

```
git commit --amend
```

Look at the history, you should be all good.

Comment: Whether the offending commit is the last one on the OP's branch is unclear. If that's not the case, `git commit --amend` is not the right command, here.

Comment: You're right, good point. Gave your answer an upvote for better formatting and a link to rebasing chapter.

Comment: Now that your answer mentions the "last-commit" limitation, you can get my upvote too :)