# How to find the original commit of an amended one?

Tags: git

Actually by an accident I found out something interesting. I amended a change to an existing local commit. I know that will *change* the hash of the original commit - at least that's what I thought. But it seems git creates a complete new commit. No problem so far.

```
$ vim foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m "Edited Foo"
$ git log --oneline -n 1
5b122c7 Edited Foo

$ vim foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit --amend
$ git log --oneline -n 1
98f1e64 Edited Foo
$ git show 5b122c7   # wait what?
```

`git show 5b122c7` will show me the original commit - so the amended commit is effictively a new commit.

But why is the old commit still in the repository? Okay it could be neat to have the original commit to go back.

But the original commit `5b122c7` does not even appear in `git log --all`
Also a `git revert 5b122c7` does not fall back to `5b122c7` but instead to the previous commit of my original one.

I'm just curious about this behavior and want to know: is there a way to find the original commit `5b122c7` with `git log` or something? In case I don't know the hash of the original commit: how can I find the hash?

Comment: it is lost in the limbos. it will be garbage collected if git ever needs space. you can't find it unless you know its sha1. consider this other case: checkout a given sha1 (not a branch). create a commit on top of it. checkout anywhere else. your new commit is in limbo (and git warns you that this happens when you enter the detached state)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly/26050416#26050416 to understand what happened to the old commit, and for a way to get it back.

Answer (score 10):

The old commit is still in the repository, but is no longer included in the history of any branch. So, `5b122c7` will eventually get cleaned up by Git's garbage collection.

There is no direct way to discover the original commit given only the hash of a new amended commit. Amending a commit is essentially throwing away the old one and making a new one. There is no link between them.

Within the repository where you amended the commit, the `git reflog` command will show the hash of the old commit. However, this is not part of what somebody else would see if they were to clone your repository.