# How can I add a file to the last commit in Git?

Tags: git

Sometimes after I did a commit, I found out that I left out a file which should also be included in the commit, but was actually not. I often committed again:

```
git add the_left_out_file
git commit "include the file which should be added in the last commit"
```

I think it might not be a good idea to do so. I want to just include the file without adding a commit. Something like this,

```
git add the_left_out_file
git add_staged_files_to_previous_commit
```

Is it possible?

Comment: also, another explanation of the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly

Comment: Found this awesome article: https://medium.com/@igor_marques/git-basics-adding-more-changes-to-your-last-commit-1629344cb9a8

Answer (score 1450, accepted):

Yes, there's a command, `git commit --amend`, which is used to "fix" the last commit.

In your case, it would be called as:

```
git add the_left_out_file
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

The *--no-edit* flag allows to make an amendment to the commit without changing the commit message.

**Warning**

You should never amend public commits that you already pushed to a public repository, because amend is actually removing the last commit from the history and creating a new commit with the combined changes from that commit and new added when amending.

Comment: I saw the EDIT in @konrad-zeguis answer *after* doing the commit... How can 'git commit --amend --no-edit' be undone?

Comment: Try 'git reset HEAD@{1}' which will put you back one commit. You can use 'git reflog' to get a full list of commits, and use it to reset to 'HEAD@{n}' where n is the commit to which you would like to roll back.

Comment: Just to remind, at the end you should use:
**git push --force**, because this way you are rewriting the commits tree

Comment: with `git status` you can get the filename and copy it instead of typing it.

Comment: If you want to push to remote repository execute this command :
**git push -f origin some_branch**
[link](https://medium.com/@igor_marques/git-basics-adding-more-changes-to-your-last-commit-1629344cb9a8)

Comment: Note that amending the commit (with or without message edit) does not change the *commit date* nor the *author*. To make it transparent when and who did what, I recommend `git commit --amend --no-edit --date=now --reset-author`

Answer (score 61):

If you didn't push the update in remote then the simple solution is
remove the last local commit using the following command:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Then add all files and commit again.

Comment: Cool trick, Muhammed!  Can you add a brief explaination about `HEAD^` to your answer?

Comment: `HEAD^` is a reference to the commit before the latest commit on the current branch. `HEAD` is a reference to the latest commit on the current branch.

Comment: ^ represents -1, and HEAD represents the current position pointer in git. Thus, HEAD^ represents 1 commit before the latest commit.

Comment: git commit --amend -m "your new message"

Comment: will it change the changes I made in local files?

Comment: Not a good answer because this command doesn't add a file to the last commit. It removes the last commit entirely to be redone, which is not the same thing.