# How can I solve "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree"?

Tags: android, git, git-bash

I have only *one* commit on `master` and haven't merged it into the `remote`. I want to remove my commit, keep my changed files, change my branch, and commit them.

Now I have used `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, but I am faced with this error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
> 'git  [...] -- [...]'

Comment: Do you mean that, currently, your `master` branch has one single commit in its history ?

Comment: yes exactly @LeGEC

Comment: I faced a similar problem. I used 
git reset --soft origin. and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HEAD~1` is a way to point at "the parent of current commit"

In your situation: the (only) commit on master does not have a parent ...

---

If your intention is to have this commit on another branch, simply create that other branch:

```
git checkout -b my/branch

# The above is a shortcut to:
git branch my/branch    # Create a new branch `my/branch` on the current commit
git checkout my/branch  # Switch to this branch
```

With one single commit in its history, "removing the commit from `master`" is the same as "deleting `master`".

There is no harm in doing it (you can re-create it later): `git branch -d master`, but you can also live with a local `master` branch hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to amend the first commit:

```
# Make your change in the file(s)
git add file_changes
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Resource: *[How can I add a file to the last commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503417/how-to-add-a-file-to-the-last-commit-in-git/40503483#40503483)*

Answer (score 0):

If this is from flutter, then the problem is simply from your installation process.
check your .git > refs , if the heads & remote directories are empty, then you simply have incomplete files.
Delete your current flutter folder and download again.
Ensure that 100% of the files are moved/copied during extraction