# Git: how this bifurcation happen?

Tags: git, commit, git-branch, git-history-graph

### Situation

- I have a local Git repo.

[image]

- **I have only on branch:** `master`.
- I used to have another branch but I merged it into `master` and then deleted it.
- Such merged and deleted branch bifurcated from `fe6263e`.
- `0c81926` was an --amend of `c79dc19`
- There is no tag nor any other comming pointing to `c79dc19`. I understand that if some object was pointing to an ammended commit, such commit would continue to show in the history. But this is not the case.

### Questions

- Why didn't the history line flattened?
- Why is still `c79dc19` showing?
- How did it happen?

As I mentioned nothing points to it and I did a `git -gc` to clean up any hanging commit.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no tag nor any other [commit] pointing to `c79dc19`

That's not what the history shows.

Try running `git show HEAD` - it'll show what the two parents of the merge are. It looks from your graph like one is the `c79dc19`, and that's why it shows up in your history.

Most likely, either the branch really started at `c79dc19` (so that was *already* on master), or the branch was merged to master as a fast-forward when `c79dc19` was its head.

---

Worked illustration:

1. initial state

   ```
   fe62 <=master <=HEAD
   ```
2. new commit

   ```
   fe62 <- c79d <=master <=HEAD
   ```
3. checkout new branch

   ```
   fe62 <- c79d <=master <=branch <=HEAD
   ```
4. amend (on branch) gives a new commit `0c81` which *replaces* `c79d` on that branch but *doesn't* change `master`

   ```
   fe62 <- c79d <=master
        \- 0c81 <=branch <=HEAD
   ```

Comment: I think this is the most likely situation. Branched off of `c79dc19` and then amended on the branch. So when the merge happened, it saw the base as `fe6263e` (the parent commit of the branch point) instead of `c79dc19`.

Comment: They do - when you amend c79, you create an alternate version of it with the same parent. So, the original c79 and the amended 0c8 show as branches from their common ancestor.

Comment: When I do `git show HEAD` if shows `Merge: c79dc19 f6429eb`.

Comment: so HEAD is pointing directly to c79 as one of its two parents, as I said.

Answer (score 2):

You created new branch from master at `c79` so master continued to point there. Then from the new branch you committed the amendment, hence master and new branch have diverged histories.

One thing to note is that an amendment doesn't actually modify the commit. Commits are immutable. An amendment creates a new commit based on another.

If you want to flatten it, then point master to the previous commit and merge to the tip.

```
git checkout -b temp
git branch -f master fe6263e
git checkout master
git merge f6429eb
```

Comment: +1 because I flattened the tree running the commands one by one. But I'm afraid I'll have to accept @Useless' answer because he explained what happened in a way I could clearly understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be 100% sure, but this happens often so this is *probably* the correct answer.

You mention that you have only one branch, named `master`.  I believe you!  But you don't have only one *repository*—or more precisely, you have your clone, and then there is some other clone, probably on a remote you call `origin` on some central server such as GitHub or a corporate server.  You send commits to the server, and get commits from the server.

You also mentioned using `git commit --amend`.  See [How does git commit --amend work, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050327/how-does-git-commit-amend-work-exactly) (as in [Jubobs' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512493/git-how-this-bifurcation-happen#comment68269336_40512493)) for details, but in short, this doesn't *change* the commit, it just *shoves it aside* in favor of the new replacement commit.  Presumably, though, you had already pushed the original commit—so now it was in the `master` branch in the *other* repository.

So you now had `0c81926` as the tip of your `master`, while they (origin) had `c79dc19`.  You then made new commit `f6429eb`, so that your `master` pointed to that.

Then, I bet you ran `git pull` (and most likely you have not configured or instructed your `git pull` to do `git rebase`).  This ran `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  The `git fetch` checked with your remote, `origin`, and found that *its* `master` pointed to commit `c79dc19`.  The `git merge` that `git pull` ran merged *their* branch with *your* branch, producing merge commit `706b1ef`.

In the end, what this means is that you *did* have two different branches: master, and master.  It's just that one of them is *your* master, and one of them is *someone else's* master.

Note that you can get rid of commit `c79dc19` *and* the merge, e.g., using `git rebase -i fe6263e` (the point just before the mess starts): delete the unwanted extra commit, and let `git rebase` flatten the remaining history and omit the merge.  (Or, use the method in [Jeff Puckett II's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513759/1256452).)  Once you do this, though, your history will be *divergent* from the history on `origin`: they have a commit (that same `c79dc19` you are trying to get rid of) that you don't.  So you won't be able to push without forcing the push (optionally, "force with lease", expecting their `master` to be `c79dc19`, to make sure they have not gotten even more commits since the last time you checked).

Comment: Very good answer but I'm afraid I have never made a fetch or a pull in that repo. I've only done local work from beginning to end.

Comment: Ah.  Some of the helpful items were obscured in your graphic (in particular the "merge branch ..." had the branch name and details pixelated away).  It looks like the accepted answer is the right one in this case.